# Does disruption orb block all visits?

Tags: werewolv.es

So based on previous game (ext-313), I (elrad) receive a disruption orb from killing abaddon N1, but according to the description, the orb blocks both user and visitor (if I understand it correctly)

But, I can still manage to lead the wolfpack kills although i received the RB message (target still die though), on d5, in the morning, a real adjudicator manage to check me without getting roleblock while myself does (still got the roleblock message though)

So, any explanation about this disruption orb mechanics is helpful, and again, does it blocks all visit (including lethal visit) and was the d5 is actually a bug?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different situations here.

In the first instance, you gained the Disruption Orb by killing its original owner. This was a bug first seen in that game, and has since been fixed. It was caused by item effects resolving before wolfpack targets.

In the second instance, the person that checked you was holding a **Ring of Tenacity**, making them immune to role-blocks. So the Adjudicator checking you was not a bug.